# How do you return your REST APIs result to java cli application?

Tags: java, rest, sockets

I have developed before with node.js and spray.io to send/receive REST API response to front-end/back-end server and vice versa, but I'm having a hard time returning a value to a java cli application (like terminal) using plain java.

I thought this could be a good practice for me to understand but it's more difficult than I thought it would be. I was able to reproduce echo servers on here https://www.cs.uic.edu/~troy/spring05/cs450/sockets/socket.html

What I want to do is to take a string parameter and send it to the spring framework to process it in the back-end, then return it to the cli application.

But just can't find an example for that.
Could anyone direct me to a good project sample that does this?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Apache `HttpClient`, a fairly simple to use and high performance library.  For example:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RestClientExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

#### References

*Home Page*: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

*Tutorial*: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this now.

Comment: So this would be throw a string into cli -> httpClient -> spring framework -> tomcat/jetty..? Or that's how I'm understanding it as. Please correct me if this is wrong!

Comment: If you mean `HttpClient` calling a Spring MVC RESTful web service deployed on Tomcat or Jetty, then yes this stack works!  Another option is the Jersey framework (https://jersey.java.net) with Dropwizard (http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs).